# How to calculate unique ID's in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have an excel sheet which contains 4 years data of schools. The data set contains school scores. Old schools have data for 3 or 4 years of data while new schools have only 1 or 2 years of data.

I have a column in my data set which represents the unique school ID's. Based on these school ID's I want to generate a column "Occurrence" which represents the number of times each unique id occurred in the data set. I am attaching a picture which shows clearly what I want to have in the occurrence column by using formula. [image: View my data set]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `G2` use:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B$2:B2,B2)=1,COUNTIF(B:B,B2),"")
```

Drag down.

Comment: The `IF` construction will only do `COUNTIF(B:B,B2)` when the first part is `TRUE`, meaning only where `COUNTIF(B$2:B2,B2)` equals one. Notice that this is a growing range the further you drag it down. Try to use `Evaluate Formula` when you don't understand and click through the steps.